# Return top N rows ordered by date after table join

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I posted a few weeks back with an issue, now I've gotten past it and found a new need and new issue. I'm using access 2010, unsure what version database, have on;y access grunt tools to use (no objects, for instance). I have a query that works, it looks like this. The goal of this query is to use one row as a baseline and find all related rows that come after it chronologically. For all I know, this may be a very crude solution.

```
SELECT QueueA.cnlyMemberId, QueueA.updateUser AS 305UpdateUser, QueueA.updateDt AS 305UpdateDt, QueueB.statusCd
FROM (SELECT cnlyMemberID, updateUser, updateDt 
      FROM V_Queue_History
      WHERE statusCd = "305" AND
            V_Queue_History.updateDt Between [Enter Start Date:] And [Enter End Date: (must be at least one day apart)]
     ) AS QueueA INNER JOIN
     V_Queue_History AS QueueB
     ON (QueueA.cnlyMemberID = QueueB.cnlyMemberID AND
         QueueA.updateDt < QueueB.updateDt
        )
```

Now what I want to do is I want to find the first 305 statusCd and the next statusCd chronologically, rather than every statusCd that follows. I've tried a few things now, mostly trying to take the TOP 2 with an ORDER BY updateDt slipped in the ON condition. Then I tried replacing the V_Queue_History with a table and doing the same, didn't work. I just tried using a where condition where I check to see if the

QueueB.cnlyMemberId is IN (SELECT TOP 2 cnlylMemberID FROM QueueB WHERE conditions);

but still nothing. The system would tell me it didn't know what QueueB was anymore, so none of it would run in the WHERE statement. I would be more specific on but I just made Access crash and my mind is starting to get hazy from how frustrating this can be. I don't have much experience with Access/SQL at all and I'm learning it pretty much as I go.

So to recap, the first query runs fine but I need to return only the row with the status updated first after the initial 305.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want without a sample output, maybe something like this would help:

```
SELECT QueueA.cnlyMemberId, QueueA.updateUser AS 305UpdateUser, QueueA.updateDt AS 305UpdateDt, QueueB.statusCd
FROM (SELECT cnlyMemberID, updateUser, updateDt 
      FROM V_Queue_History
      WHERE statusCd = "305" AND
            V_Queue_History.updateDt Between [Enter Start Date:] And [Enter End Date: (must be at least one day apart)]
     ) AS QueueA INNER JOIN
     V_Queue_History AS QueueB
     ON QueueA.cnlyMemberID = QueueB.cnlyMemberID
WHERE (QueueB.updateDt = 
   (SELECT Min(updateDt) FROM V_Queue_History V2
    WHERE V2.cnlyMemberID = QueueA.cnlyMemberID 
    AND V2.updateDt > QueueA.updateDt))
```

This assumes there is always a status code after the 305, and also that no two records have the same update date.

If you need to get the top N status codes after the 305 then you could change the WHERE clause as following, although I don't know if the performance will be good enough for your situation:

```
WHERE QueueB.updateDt IN 
   (SELECT TOP 5 updateDt FROM V_Queue_History V2
    WHERE V2.cnlyMemberID = QueueA.cnlyMemberID 
    AND V2.updateDt > QueueA.updateDt
    ORDER BY V2.updateDt)
```

Comment: Sorry, this was kind of a rush job. I could make up some tables and fake rows to get the idea across, but I can't use actual data. Give me a moment to try this.

Comment: Well it certain does seem to be pretty close to what I want, I'll need to test it more. For the sake of understand, what you mind briefly explaining what the Min() function is doing here?

Comment: It's getting the earliest updateDt that is after the 305 updateDt for a particular memberID.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. In the event I need a bit more data, is there a way to make it get the n soonest rather than just the first? I think this will work otherwise, but I just want to cover bases. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just saw the update. Awesome stuff, thanks! What you posted in the Edit was what I was looking for but kept mixing up my tables and aliases. That being said, the performance is a lot better with the first one and I have a good idea how to modify it as I need. Thanks for your help!